# How can I change Windows 10 context menu option for New > Text Document to open Notepad++?

Tags: windows-10, context-menu

Instead of using Notepad as the default text editor that opens when I click New > Text Document in Windows 10 context menu, I'd like for it to open Notepad++, instead.  Is there a way that I can do this?

EDIT: I should clarify that I don't want to add a new option to the context menu.  Rather, I'd like to replace the program that opens when I click New > Text Document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### When I click "New" > "Text Document", I'd like for it to open `Notepad++`.

Set `Notepad++` to be the default application for text files.

1. Click Menu > "Settings" > "Preferences"
2. Click "File Association"
3. Under "Supported extension", select "Notepad", then select ".txt"
4. Click "->"
5. This will add ".txt" to "Registered extensions"

   - Click "Customise" Add any other extensions you want the be registered, for example `.text` or similar that are not in of the existing lists.
6. Click "Close"
7. Restart `Notepad++`

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]